# Can Apple Aluminium Keyboard be saved after coffee spill?

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

Today I spilled some coffee on my Apple Keyboard. I cleaned up the spill with an towel. At first the keyboard seemed to be working fine, but then a couple of keys stopped working. When I noticed that I disconnected the keyboard. Is there anything I can do to save the keyboard?

I probably should have disconnected the keyboard immediately, but now it's too late.

Comment: http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/77/What+should+I+do+after+I+spill+liquid+on+my+device

Comment: possible duplicate of [I just spilt coffee on my laptop, what should I do?](http://superuser.com/questions/11995/i-just-spilt-coffee-on-my-laptop-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you thoroughly [clean your keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1331/how-to-clean-a-keyboard), and allow it to completely dry, and then give it another shot.

If it still doesn't work after then, you're probably out of luck.