# Coffee is spilled on my Lenovo Laptop

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I just spilt coffee on my laptop, what should I do?](https://superuser.com/questions/11995/i-just-spilt-coffee-on-my-laptop-what-should-i-do)

A coffee was spilt over my Lenovo T500 laptop. It reached the battery and the screen.

Now, when pressing the power button, the laptop starts while the screen doesn't turn on at all, and then shuts down after 1 minute.

What should I do?

Comment: Go get another coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not much:

- remove power cord,
- take out the battery,
- optionally remove some mechanical parts (e.g. keyboard) but make sure this does not interfere with warranty conditions...
- turn the notebook so remaining fluid can run out
- comment by churnd: if there is residue built up on internal components, you'd need to take them out & rinse them off with distilled water, then let them dry completely.

  - You can pat them dry with a lint free cloth, but best to let them sit for a few days
- you could carefully dry with a hairdryer...
- and be **patient**(!) until all fluids are dry...

then check if it is still working.

Comment: +1 for the patient. prefer to not test or power any of these devices when you are already aware of liquids getting into the electronics. 99% rubbing alcohol can be used to "replace" or push  water out , and will dry faster, but still giving days to dry before powering is critical.     Alcohol can mess up some plastics and get behind screens, get under membrane Kbs and all. we use it carefully here to clean-up or finish a clean-up so it can get back into action faster.

Comment: yep. carful with "chemicals". because you own a lenovo you could also remove the keyboard to let it dry faster. at least the thinkpad series used to allow this. not sure on other models.

Comment: If there is residue built up on internal components, you'd need to take them out & rinse them off with distilled water, then let them dry completely.  You can pat them dry with a lint free cloth, but best to let them sit for a few days.

Comment: @churnd: very useful comment! I integrated it in the answer. thanks.

Comment: You can also use 99% isopropyl alcohol with a lint free cloth & splash/dab components to clear up water/condensation/debris.  I would only use it after using distilled water to clean the components.