# Acer One laptop does not power up after spilled coffee

Tags: laptop

I accidently spilled a small amount of coffee on my Acer laptop.
I was already powered off.  I dried it a couple of days and then tried to start the laptop.

...only the fan is spinning and the light on the power button is off.

When I disassembled the laptop completely it showed no visual damage on the mainboard etc. and it had no coffee stains or burned amplifiers etc.

A thing is that when I try to start the laptop without the keyboard connected the laptop begins to start but immedialtly stops, but now the light of the powerbutton is on.

So the question is if it could be so that it might be a keyboard error?

Br Mike

Comment: possible duplicate of [I just spilt coffee on my laptop, what should I do?](http://superuser.com/questions/11995/i-just-spilt-coffee-on-my-laptop-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 2):

Although your laptop was powered off at the time of the spill, it likely shorted out when you powered it on. Even though it was left to dry for a couple days, moisture can still exist between parts and in crevasses. As soon as you energized the system, the current can cross the liquid causing a short which causes additional damage.

It should have been dismantled and cleaned before turning it back on. By taking it apart you've removed some of the short circuit but as you are experiencing, the damage is done.

You may want to take it to someone who can determine where the damage is and what it will take to repair it.