# Acer Aspire Keyboard Issue

Tags: keyboard, acer-aspire, water-damage

5 days ago I spilled some water on my laptop computer.  The only problem I had was the keyboard was not working correctly.  I removed it and everything underneath was dry, as the keyboard comes out from the top and there was some plastic covering on the bottom of it. I can use the on screen keyboard and mouse just fine.  Everything within the computer seems to be fine, it operates as usual, minus the keyboard not working. I bought a new keyboard and replaced it, but some of the keys do not work, specifically home row and like every other key on the other rows.  It seems like to me I have seen another computer have this problem and it was an easy fix, but then again maybe not.  I really depend on my computer as I am an online student and I would be so greatful if anyone could offer their thoughts.
the model is  acer aspire E1-531

Comment: Please edit your question to include the make and model of your laptop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I just spilt coffee on my laptop, what should I do?](http://superuser.com/questions/11995/i-just-spilt-coffee-on-my-laptop-what-should-i-do)